# Check if Windows service is stopped manually or due to some exception

Tags: c#, windows-services

How would I be able to know that the service is stopped due to some exception or stopped manually in the following event?

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    if (Service is stopped manually)
    {
        //Log Something
    }
    else if (Service is stopped due to some exception)
    {
        GenerateNotification();
        //Log Something here
    }

    timer.Stop();
    timer = null;
}
```

My `OnStart` event is as follows:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{

    timer = new Timer(ConfigurationReader.IntervalInSeconds * 1000D);
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ProcessNotifications);
    timer.Start();
}
```

> Actually when I'm stopping the sevice manually, I dont want some of
>   the logic to be executed..But when its stopped due to some exception,
>   I need to do some logic

Comment: Use exception handling and logging

Comment: I'm already doing it..Can you see my updated question?

Comment: That's what I meant by exception handling...put the code that should only run if there was an exception in a `catch` block

Comment: For your updated question you need to show us your starting code. Also the code of any timers or threads or tasks that get started in the OnStartup code.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - You can see my updated question. This will give you better idea what I want. I just want to check if service is stopped from Services.msc or its stopped due to some exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error will be in windows event log, but exception doesn't call onStop.
You can handle exceptions in worker method and log all exception data, and in onStop method you can log info about normal stop.

When you stop service in normaly way then service manager call onStop method, then you don't need to do nothig.
But if exception occurs you can handle it in onStart method or in worker method and there can do extra logic. 
Stop in exception case don't call onStop method.

In your case:

```
private void ProcessNotificationsWithExceptionHandling()
{
    try
    {
        ProcessNotifications();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        GenerateNotification();
        //Log Something here
    }
}
```

And change:

```
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ProcessNotifications);
```

to

```
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ProcessNotificationsWithExceptionHandling);
```

Comment: Are you sure about this that `Stop in exception case don't call onStop method`. Stop in exception calls `OnStart` event?

Comment: Make test. In worker code throw an excpetion and check what happen. No stop in any way don't call `onStart`. But start service call `onStart`, and in this place service makes his work which can cause same exception. So here is right place to catch it.

Comment: my upvote for you. I didnt know that It wont call `OnStop` event in case of exceptional stop. Thanks!